# MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged Event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a pretty small and overall simple app, and I want to watch what zune or other apps are playing, I'm not playing media in my app.

So I thought I would use the MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged Event, but when the event does get called it crashes my app to the home screen.

```
(...)
public MainPage()
{
    //other initialization
    MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(songchanged);
}

void songchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Song changed");
}
(...)
```

This is pretty much how I've seen it done it [samples](http://books.google.de/books?id=2bnCpIQqP1UC&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=mediaplayer.activesongchanged&source=bl&ots=UIIoA-wGlQ&sig=F_weQlAU6Nxuuy4VQWNcc0LlFg8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qjHzTt-4B8iOsAbx46nZDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mediaplayer.activesongchanged&f=false) and other people's code, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.I've also tried just `MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += songchanged` with the same result.
The code inside the songchanged method doesn't actually matter, even when it's empty it still crashes.
Do I need to implement something else to get a proper eventhandler that calls my method?

Some other test code I was putting in a button also causes random crashes when the song changes...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaPlayer.Queue != null)
    {
        double length = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration.TotalSeconds;

        double pos = MediaPlayer.PlayPosition.TotalSeconds;

        if (pos != 0 && MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 100 * pos / length;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine and updates a progressbar to the current song's progress when pressed, but if I change the song after I've used the button the app also crashes to the home screen!
Sometimes right on the first song change, sometimes I can change a few songs before it happens.
This is without any of the previous code, and the button is the only thing interacting with the progressbar.

Since there is no zune in the emulator, I have to test this app on my device - unfortunately I can't debug on my device (it's unlocked, registered, and apps deploy, but fail to launch for debugging. They launch fine manually, but I can't debug), so I don't have a clue what is actually going wrong here.

Comment: You should be able to debug on your device. Are you using WPConnect instead of Zune on your PC? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: I am using WPConnect, I still get "The application could not be launched for debugging" though.

Comment: Try this suggestion: http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/the-application-could-not-be-launched-for-debugging-when-using-the-wp7-emulator/ I remember this worked before on a previous SO question so hopefully it works here (at least to get the debugger working)

Comment: I tried the link, thanks. However my configurations are all set to build & deploy, which they do, but they still don't launch for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are building a Silvelight application. Did you implement the **FrameworkDispatcher.Update** service? You must do it, and [here is how you can accomplish this task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff842408.aspx).

**Debugging problem:** might happen if you have multiple projects in one solution, some of them being non-WP7 (e.g. Windows applications).

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the FrameworkDispatcher. Event triggers fine now :)   I only have one project in my solution though, I've never been able to debug on the device even with unaltered auto-generated projects.